# Fuzzy Wuzzy to match names

Tags: python, python-3.x, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to match names with a list of names

```
text_to_match = "sa"
print(process.extract(text_to_match, ['sachin','saurabh','Amol'],scorer=fuzz.WRatio))
```

The results I got are as below

```
[('sachin', 90), ('saurabh', 90), ('Amol', 33)]
```

However i was expecting that since `sa` matched only with only partial letters of `sachin` it should have given a much smaller score but it gave a very high result.

What can I do to get better results as per requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scoring to be more strict, instead of using `fuzz.WRatio`, you can just use `fuzz.ratio`.

```
text_to_match = "sa"
print(process.extract(text_to_match, ['sachin','saurabh','Amol'],scorer=fuzz.ratio))
```

Assuming your requirement is that partial matches should not get a high score, this change should help.